# I want replace the values of 1 in an adjacency matrix with weights given in another smaller matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, adjacency-matrix

How can I replace the values of 1 in an adjacency matrix with weights given in another matrix?
For example:

```
adjacent_matrix = [1 0 0 1; 0 0 1 1; 1 0 1 0; 0 1 1 0 ]
weight_matrix = [ 2 4 6 2; 4 5 1 3]
```

The final matrix should look like this: `[2 0 0 4; 0 0 6 2; 4 0 5 0; 0 1 3 0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`accumarray` solution:

```
>> [ii,jj] = find(adjacent_matrix.');
>> out = accumarray([ii jj],reshape(weight_matrix.',[],1)).'
out =
     2     0     0     4
     0     0     6     2
     4     0     5     0
     0     1     3     0
```

`sparse` solution:

```
[ii,jj] = find(adjacent_matrix.');
out = full(sparse(ii,jj,weight_matrix.')).'
```

Answer (score 5):

Code -

```
out = adjacent_matrix';
out(out==1) = reshape(weight_matrix',1,numel(weight_matrix))';
out = out';
```

Inputs 'adjacent_matrix' and 'weight_matrix' stay the same, as suggested by @chappjc.

Comment: You need to transpose `weight_matrix` too. Adding some explanation for the OP would be nice too.

Comment: @Praetorian Don't think so.

Comment: @Praetorian Compare that with OP's desired result.

Comment: It matches because I accidentally posted the correct code. Look again.

Comment: @Divakar Don't make `adjacent_matrix` the output. It causes confusion because the input changes.  @Praetorian is right though.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was doing transpose on weight_matrix right at the start with the input, so missed out on that! Appreciate the help!